# sqlmetal.exe not found in path even though it is on my machine in the correct path - Linqer Program

Tags: c#, path, sdk, sqlmetal, linqer

I am trying to run Linqer (a program for sql -> linq) and getting this error when creating a DB connection, and trying to generate "linq to sql model files".

Error: File `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools/SqlMetal.exe not found`

Shown here:[image]

I have the file in the folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools,

How can I set it to use v10.0A instead of v8?

I have checked I have installed all microsoft SDKs on Visual Studio.
How do I set the correct path for this?
 I would appreciate any help on this!
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is telling you that it can't find it in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\**v8.0A**\bin\**NETFX 4.0 Tools**/
```

whereas you're looking in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\**v10.0A**\bin\**NETFX 4.6.2 Tools**/
```

Set the correct path on the SQLMetal Options dialog.

Comment: @Liam added a bit to the answer.

Comment: could you go in to a bit more detail, how do I open the dialog?

Comment: It's open in your screenshot, with the error message on top of it. Top entry SQLMetal Path.

Answer (score 0):

Please go and Search in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" with term "SqlMetal.exe"

I got "not found" error in this location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\SqlMetal.exe

But it was there here.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\SqlMetal.exe

NETFX 4.5.1  is the difference. Please try once again.